# Flask app deployed on IIS fails to handle unicode in URL

Tags: flask, iis, utf-8, fastcgi, wfastcgi

I have a Flask app with a route defined like this:

```py
@app.route("/api/<value>")
def foo(value):
    ...
```

On my local machine, using Flask development server, everything works correctly.

But on production, where the app is deployed on IIS using `wfastcgi`, I get a 404 error when `name` contains non-ascii characters. In IIS logs the route seems OK (shown on the log file as UTF-8) but on the Flask side the request is received with gibberish characters. The following method:

```py
@app.before_request
def log_request():
    req: flask.Request = request
    logger.info(
        f"{req.method} {req.path}}"
    )
```

prints this to the log:

```
GET /api/�
```

This is more than just a display issue. The value itself is incorrect and I can't use it to process the request correctly.

I tried to use the `quote` and `unquote` methods from the `urllib` package but it does not seem to solve the problem.

Is there any setting on IIS I can use to fix this?

(IIS 10, Flask 1.1.2)

Comment: Have you checked Allow high-bit characters in IIS? IIS manager -> Request Fitering -> Feature Settings, select Allow high-bit characters.

Comment: Yes, it is already checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following on [Microsoft's documentation for PHP with FastCGI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configuring-the-fastcgi-extension-for-iis-60#configuring-fastcgi). I worked for me with Flask/wfastcgi as well:

> By default, the FastCGI extension uses ASCII encoding when setting server variables that are used by PHP. When the requested URL contains non-ASCII characters, server variables that derive their values from the requested URL string may be set incorrectly. PHP applications that rely on those server variables may not work as a result.

> To prevent this, the FastCGI extension can be configured to use UTF-8 encoding when setting server variables. To configure FastCGI to use UTF-8 encoding for a particular set of server variables, use the REG_MULTI_SZ registry key FastCGIUtf8ServerVariables and set its value to a list of server variable names. For example:

> `reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\w3svc\Parameters /v FastCGIUtf8ServerVariables /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d REQUEST_URI\0PATH_INFO`
> The above example configures the FastCGI extension to use UTF-8 encoding when setting the REQUEST_URI and PATH_INFO server variables.

> After setting the registry key, restart IIS by using the iisreset command.